# How to localize package siunitx to spanish?

Tags: babel, siunitx

I'm writing a report where I use units inside a table. In few cases I need to use a range with units. But since I'm writing not in English (actually in Spanish) The result of a range using the preopisition to (asi in English) isn't useful for me.
 So, is there a way to write a range with `\SIrange` correctly in something different from English or should I forget it and do it manually?

A kind sort of MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{4in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} rYS[table-format=2.3] @{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Parámetros geométricos del modelo} & Valor \\ 
\midrule
$d$:  & diámetro & \SI{.59}{[\milli\metre]} \\
$ph$: & altura de la placa & \SI{3.5}{[\milli\metre]} \\
$l$:  & longitud o ancho de la placa & \SIrange{10}{50}{[\milli\metre]} \\
$L$:  & longitud del vaso & \SI{200}{[\milli\metre]} \\         
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}                      
\caption[Parámetros geométricos]{Parámetros geométricos.}
\label{taula:pargeom}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\documentclass[spanish]{scrartcl}`

Comment: I'll be adding Spanish support to the next release :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a lack of spanish at this time:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { iraultza }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
        \SIrange{10}{50}{\milli\metre}
\end{document}
```

`siunitx` works closely with package `translator`. You can contribute by translating other strings and bring it to the project.

Comment: Indeed: last point is key! I can only cover languages I know reasonably well or have some contributions for :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Is there a list of words which need translation somewhere?

Comment: @Ignasi You need to define `to (numerical range)` in addition to the basics. If that one can be supplied I can add Spanish to the languages that `siunitx` knows.

Comment: @JosephWright In Spanish and Catalan `to` can be translated as `a`, like in Bernard's answer.

Comment: @Ignasi You mean `a` is the appropriate value? If so, I'll add.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, it is.

Comment: How can I contribute? In the [Github repo](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx) for `siunitx`, the [locale file](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/master/siunitx-locale.dtx) contains just 5 locales. I want to contribute mine, but it seems that they don't receive PR for this.

Comment: @minh i suggest to join the chat and ask Joseph directly. He is a mod here.

Answer (score 4):

The `translator` package should be loaded by `siunitx` if  there were a spanish dictionary. There isn't so we have to use the tools provided by siunitx. I also suggest another layout for the table (2nd table):

```
\documentclass[spanish]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,
table-space-text-post =\si{\milli\metre},
table-unit-alignment = left,
list-final-separator = { \translate{y} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{y} },
range-phrase = { \translate{a} },
range-units =single
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
  \begin{tabularx}{4in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} rYS[table-format=1.2] @{\kern\tabcolsep}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parámetros geométricos del modelo} & Valor \\
    \midrule
    $d$: & diámetro & .59\si{\,[\milli\metre]} \\
    $ph$: & altura de la placa & 3.5\si{\,[\milli\metre]} \\
    $l$: & longitud o ancho de la placa & {\SIrange{10}{50}{[\milli\metre]}} \\
    $L$: & longitud del vaso & {\SI{200}{[\milli\metre]}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Parámetros geométricos]{Parámetros geométricos.}
  \label{taula:pargeom}
\end{table}
\vskip3ex
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
  \begin{tabularx}{4in}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} rYS[table-format=1.2] @{\kern\tabcolsep}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Parámetros geométricos del modelo} & Valor\, [\si{\milli\metre}]\\
    \midrule
    $d$: & diámetro & .59 \\
    $ph$: & altura de la placa & 3.5 \\
    $l$: & longitud o ancho de la placa & {\numrange{10}{50}} \\
    $L$: & longitud del vaso & {200} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[Parámetros geométricos]{Parámetros geométricos.}
  \label{taula:pargeom}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer!!! I didnt' knew that package `translator`. About the table, is a good suggestion but my real tables have different units so I don't add it to the head.